# Powershell script to switch network adapters not working

Tags: networking, powershell, adapter

This is my first Powershell script so learning here. But I ran into a problem that if I paste the script into powershell running as admin it works perfectly but when I click on the ps1 file it doesnt elevate to admin as it does when I have it just switching a single adapter.

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}
$Connection = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Property NetConnectionID,NetConnectionStatus | Where-Object { $_.NetConnectionStatus -eq 2 } | Select-Object -Property NetConnectionID -ExpandProperty NetConnectionID

if( $Connection -eq "Wi-Fi"){
   Disable-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi -Confirm:$false
   Enable-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet -Confirm:$false
} elseif( $Connection -eq "Ethernet"){
   Disable-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet -Confirm:$false
   Enable-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi -Confirm:$false
}
```

The single adapter switch is working perfectly to elevate to admin though so I dont understand why this doesnt work on the switching script! Here is what does work:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}
Disable-NetAdapter -Name Wi-Fi -Confirm:$false
Enable-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your If statements are not properly handling the strings. The lines:

```
if($Connection -eq Wi-Fi){
```

and

```
elseif($Connection -eq Ethernet){
```

Should be:

```
if($Connection -eq "Wi-Fi"){
```

and

```
elseif($Connection -eq "Ethernet"){
```

Notice how the strings **Wi-Fi** and **Ethernet** are enclosed in double quotes. Single quotes will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
#Up is the status for a connected network adapter and Disconnected is the status for one that isn't.
$up = "Up"
$wifi = "Wi-Fi"
$lan = "Ethernet"

$wifiUp = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $up -and $_.Name -match $wifi }
$lanUp = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $up -and $_.Name -match $lan }

if ($lanUp)
{
    Write-Host("Ethernet is Connected")
}
elseif ($wifiUp) 
{
    Write-Host("Wifi is Connected")
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-Fi" -Confirm:$false
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet" -Confirm:$false
}
elseif ($wifiUp -And $lanup) 
{
    Write-Host("Both are Connected")
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-Fi" -Confirm:$false
}
else 
{
    Write-Host("All Disconnected")
}
```